# Conditional Statement based on value of a different column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to efficiently add another element to this code below, that takes into account the value of another column in this df.

Below I have a filter if the value column is `>= 0`, but I want to add an element that says if the column called `day = 'Friday'`, thanks.

`df[df['value']] >= 0`

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
df[(df['value']>=0) & (df['day']=='friday') ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Chain another condition with `&` for bitwise `AND` or `|` for bitwise `OR` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), here are necessary `()`:

```
df1 = df[(df['value'] >= 0) & (df['day'] == 'friday')]
```

Or use [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) functions for compare:

```
df1 = df[df['value'].gt(0) & df['day'].eq('friday')]
```

Or use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("(value >= 0) & (day == 'friday')")
```